# Using MLkNN for Multilabel Classification returned error message

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

I would appreciate if someone could help with the forllowing error message. My Script is as follows:

```
 from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN
 from sklearn.metrics import hamming_loss, accuracy_score
 mlknn_classifier = MLkNN()
 mlknn_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
 predicted = mlknn_classifier.predict(X_test)
 print(predicted)
 print(accuracy_score(y_test, predicted))
 print(hamming_loss(y_test,predicted))
```

The error message was as follows:
TypeError: NearestNeighbors.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has been [fixed](https://github.com/scikit-multilearn/scikit-multilearn/pull/231/commits/f46946a50c0ab02a72aa28913fb850a2ceb4a709) years ago.  The quick and dirty solution is to apply the same fix to your local skmultilearn installation.

If you have installed via pip, in .../site-packages/skmultilearn/adapt/mlknn.py change the line

```
        self.knn_ = NearestNeighbors(self.k).fit(X)
```

to

```
        self.knn_ = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=self.k).fit(X)
```